# .NET routes from database memory consideration

Tags: c#, .net, iis, memory, routes

Trying to compare the pros and cons of forming routes from database. Say we have table of articles.

- mysite.org/articles/how-to-make-icecream
- mysite.org/articles/{articleId}/how-to-make-icecream

Comparing the above routes, the first route looks cleaner but needs a for loop when title and id are fetched from database and stored in the `RouteValueDictionary` object. But the second one is generic and needs only one line of code to add the route.

If I prefer to go with the first, cleaner route:

- is there any memory or count limit on how many routes the runtime/IIS will load in memory
- will storing a whole bunch of routes in memory - maybe thousands - require any modification to default application pool settings?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any technical problem with the database solution: even thousands of Routes should only take up a few megabytes of RAM.  From an engineering perspective, you're adding another point of failure that can take down your site.  The database will work great until one day it doesn't.  Putting the id in the url is a very standard solution, and your users won't care.